# How to not skip first row when iterating in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

I have been assigned with very very bad excel data. Data have no headers and only data provided in excel.

Excel data looks like

```
1:23:32   32.43    43.30
9.2       1:23:32  3.3.2
33219.2   23:32    2.3
```

When I iterate each column, Pandas iterator automatically skips the first row. Is there a way to not skip the first row when iterating? or how to read also the first row when iterating?

```
for i, value in df.iteritems():
    print(i, value)
```

Look at my data: data are misplaced, wrong data, wrong format and, no header.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `header=None` when you use `pd.read_excel` (or `pd.read_csv`) because the first row is not a row but the column names.

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=None)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         0        1      2
0  1:23:32    32.43  43.30
1      9.2  1:23:32  3.3.2
2  33219.2    23:32    2.3
```